# Generate variables using loop parameter

Tags: python, c, embedded, pic

I want to manage a large number of variables. my program will be large if i compare each variable separately. I want to run a for loop and compare all the variables. the code may be in c for pic micro controller or in python.

```
 id1= id2=id3=.......=True
 c="id"
 for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
  {
    c=c+str(i)
    if(check the value of id's are true)
    }
```

Now the value of c is id1 which is a string ,not the variable id1. Is there any way to use the value of c as the variable as id1?

Comment: your example is not clear enough can you make it more clear with examples.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If the boolean variables are added to a list, managing them is simple. They could be a tuple or custom class if additional properties are needed to be associated as well, beyond just the index / pointer to the specific variable.

Comment: Do you want an array `id[100]`?

Comment: C is a language, "pic micro controller" _is not_.

Comment: Why is this titled "Generate variables...", the question suggests no such thing.  If `id1` is a string, how come you are initialising it and testing it  with a _Boolean!_?   Not much about this question makes any sense, but you probably need an array or some iteratable container supported by whatever language you settle on. You cannot iterate independent variables in C, not sure about Python, but you should probably decide on a language before asking the question in any case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to perform easy comparison without using for loop.
Now you want all the ids to be True.

you can do this, rather than defining id variables individually, use a list instead, where each value will correspond to one of your id. Like id1 id2 and id3 will be represented by ids[0],ids[1] and ids[1] respectively.

Now after making list, if you want to see if all the values are true, just do this.

```
boolean_val = all(ids)
```

if boolean_val is True, it means all the values that is variables in the list are true, else one of them may be false.

Hopefully this ans your doubt.